# Visual appearance is not updated for UWP custom control in VS designer

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, uwp-xaml

I have a Windows 10 UWP custom control that is deployed as an extension SDK.
The control's generic.xaml looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="local:PdfDocumentView" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:PdfDocumentView">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PdfScroller" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <local:PdfCoreView x:Name="PdfPageView" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The layout of the extension SDK looks like this:
Redist\CommonConfiguration\neutral\Themes\generic.xaml
Redist\CommonConfiguration\neutral\Xfinium.Pdf.View.Uwp.pri
References\CommonConfiguration\neutral\xfinium.pdf.uwp.dll
References\CommonConfiguration\neutral\xfinium.pdf.render.uwp.dll
References\CommonConfiguration\neutral\xfinium.pdf.view.uwp.dll

There are no architecture specific folders as the control is pure .NET compiled using AnyCPU option.
At design time I drag the PdfDocumentView control from the toolbox on the page and set the Background, BorderBrush and BorderThickness properties.

If the active platform is set to x86, the control appearance is updated in the designer according to the above 3 properties. If the active platform is changed to x64 or ARM the control becomes transparent, as if none of the above properties is set.

At runtime the control is displayed ok, all 3 properties are considered, no matter the platform, x86 or x64.

What could be the problem with the VS designer and the x64 platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK it's a problem of the designer that is not working really great for any platform except x86. You'll have to live with it.

However they're working on a new, much faster designer supporting more features and that *upgrade* may even resolve this issue. Read more about it in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/09/11/a-significant-update-to-the-xaml-designer/).